# Creating a customizable high pressure extensions line for cga 580

Tags: kegging

So I'm trying to set up a keg on nitro. The way my room is laid out, id like to have the n2 cylinder far away from the regulator and keg. One side of this setup requires cga580 male, the other side requires cga 580 female.

Because of the specifics of this setup I need the line to be a high pressure line that can connect directly to the cylinder.

So my goal is to essentially make an extension cable that I can place different cga 580 ends on. I've seen this referred to as a `pigtail`.

I can't figure out which parts will fit which other parts though. I bought this expensive cga580 male to male pigtail thinking I could remove one of the male heads but I can't remove the head.

Does anyone know if getting a stainless pigtail with 1/4 npt female ends would allow me to add adapters that are 1/4 npt to cga 580?

If so could someone point me towards the adapters that will allow this setup?

Or if not, does anyone know og anywhere that sells a cga 580 male to female pigtail?

Or any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I would try to make something that would be handling full tank pressure.

I personally use a high pressure hose from my CO2 tank to my regulator bank, but I didn't make the hose myself.

Here's a [high pressure nitrogen hose](https://www.kegoutlet.com/rg511n-high-pressure-nitrogen-hose-regulator-connection-hose.html) that can be used to offset your regulator from your nitrogen tank.

Good luck and stay safe!